# How to add a button to a compact framework DataGrid?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is it possible to add a button to a column in the DataGrid for the compact framework?  So far the only thing I can find is you can add textbox and that's it.  What would be a good alternative to a DataGrid that can allow other controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DataGrid's

```
public Rectangle GetCellBounds(int row, int col);
```

with

```
public event EventHandler CurrentCellChanged;
public DataGridCell CurrentCell { get; set; }
```

or

```
public event MouseEventHandler MouseMove;
public HitTestInfo HitTest(int x, int y);
```

to show a Button (or another control) over the selected cell.

Regards,
tamberg