# How to add a new column to delete a Datagrid's row, Windows mobile

Tags: c#, datagrid, windows-mobile

I am developing an application for windows mobile in `C#` (`visual studio 2008`) and `sql server 2008`

I use a "select" to display columns in a `DataGrid`:

```
                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DATOST", conn);
                da.Fill(ds, "DATOST");
                dtgLista.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

and it shows something like [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC148932.gif)

What I'm trying to do is to add a new column with the word `remove` and when it be selected delete the row.

I tried with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/x8x9zk5a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

--- and more links I can't write because i need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links---

But My app doesn´t work

**Any easier idea please?**

*Thank You*

Comment: When you add special keyword like `remove` use []. For e.g. `[remove]`

Comment: Okay @Sameer Thank you, sorry

Comment: The second link is pointing to a Full Framework .net 4.5 example. That will not work on Windows Mobile, where only Comapct Framework up to version 3.5 is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact Framework, which the .net runtime running on Windows Mobile, does not support button or other elements within a datagrid. Only EditBox is supported by default.

There are already questions and answers on how to add a button or checkBox to a compact framework datagrid here at stackoverflow:

[How to add a button to a compact framework DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285111/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-compact-framework-datagrid)

[Attach button to column datagrid in C# Compact Framework .Net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596067/attach-button-to-column-datagrid-in-c-sharp-compact-framework-net-2-0)

and

[display images in datagrid with Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969937/display-images-in-datagrid-with-compact-framework)

and at other sides like: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/caee833d-f0ac-496f-b13c-b87116450f39/how-to-add-a-button-in-a-datagrid

The solution is to add a custom paint handler for datacells.

There are also commercial extended datagrid controls available that support more than only EditBox: for example Resco SmartDrid control: [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29021/Grid-Control-for-NET-Compact-Framework) at codeproject. I am sure there are other vendors too. Just use a internet search "compact framework datagrid add button".

Answer (score -1):

You can add delete bottun to datagridview

```
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DATOST", conn);
        da.Fill(ds, "DATOST");
        DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        col.Text = "REmove";
        col.Name = "MyButton";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        dtgLista.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.CellContentClick);
```

and then write event handler to remove the selected row

```
    private void CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //make sure click not on header and column is type of ButtonColumn
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && ((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonColumn))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks great @user3216429 Do I need some `using`?

Comment: No, You don't need any more using

Comment: What could I do? It says: **Can not find the type or namespace name 'DataGridViewButtonColumn' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** @mnshahab

Comment: Do I need a `datatable`? or something else? @mnshahab

Comment: You can try to do manually by create datatable. but the above code works good in my machine visual stadio 2010

Comment: 1. VS201 is not able to do Windows Mobile (SmartDevice) projects. 2. The DataGridViewButtonColumn is not available in Compact Famework.

Comment: But properties like `.CurrentRow`, `.Rows` and `.Columns` are not available @mnshahab, What could I do? @josef